# Converting object type string to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, expression, eval

how to convert `{ startItem: 2 }` string to an object
`{ "startItem": 2 }` without using eval() function ?

Comment: is `aux` a string or an object?

Comment: aux is a string

Comment: Where does `window.dzsztm_self_options` come from?   You could use `window["dzsztm_self_options"] = aux` to set a global variable, then dzsztm_self_options can be a variable, eg `var auxname = "dzsztm_self_options"; window[auxname] = aux`.

Comment: i tried `window["dzsztm_self_options"] = aux` but it also prints the string only instead of object

Comment: To use JSON.parse, you would need *valid* JSON, eg `'{"startItem":2}'` (at least for the aux part), you'd still need to assign to a variable.

Comment: where do yo get `aux` from? why not use the object directly or a string in [JSON](https://json.org/) fromat?

Comment: aux is coming dynamically. It's in library. so can't change it. It might affect other things.

Comment: then you need to take `eval`.

Comment: Does the library documentation say how you're supposed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var aux = { startItem: 2 }
var jsonStr = aux.replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) {
                      return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
});
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(obj);
```

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.stringify()

Example run in chrome console:

```
> JSON.stringify({ startItem: 2 })
  '{"startItem":2}'
```

And JSON.parse the other way :

```
> JSON.parse('{"startItem":2}')
  {startItem: 2}
```

Edit:

So you have a string '{ startItem: 2 }'. And you dont want to use eval, then you can use Function:

```
> const transform = (value) => Function(`return ${value}`)()
> transform('{ startItem: 2}')
  {startItem: 2}
```

And then you can JSON.stringify this one.

Comment: Their original string is not valid JSON syntax, it doesn't have quotes around the key.

Comment: Edited to handle the first transformation.

Comment: Using `Function()` has all the same problems as using `eval()`.